# unexpected Error in reduce

Tags: pyspark

While finding max value with reduce in pyspark i am getting the below unexpected result.

```
agg.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a > b else b )
```

and my sample data is

```
  (u'2013-10-17', 80325.0)
(u'2014-01-01', 68521.0)
(u'2013-11-10', 83691.0)
(u'2013-11-14', 149289.0)
(u'2013-11-18', 94756.0)
(u'2014-01-30', 126171.0)
```

and result is

**(u'2014-07-24', 97088.0)**

It should gave result more than 94756

Thanks
sPradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the second value in tuple, like this:

```
agg.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a[1] > b[1] else b )
```

Comment: I apologies for late response , Thanks for the help @Mariusz

Answer (score 1):

Just use `max` with `key`:

```
rdd.max(key=lambda x: x[1])
```